# Getting error when running solana-test validator

Tags: solana-cli, solana-test-validator

Getting this error

```
Error: failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: blockstore error
```

when running solana-test-validator on m1

Comment: also running into the same error on Ventura. tried various solana versions

Comment: @DevBharel delete the test ledger folder and restart your Mac and try again, this works for me.

Comment: Do you build solana locally? I didn't manage to reproduce the problem (rust 1.65) `./validator/solana-test-validator`

Comment: No, I just install it from the recommended section from solana docs.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted my answer in a duplicate question to this. https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/4761/3019 Hope it helps.

Comment: This solved the issue for me on MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 M1 with solana-cli 1.14.18 and rustc pinned to 1.65.0 using a rust-toolchain.toml