# solana-test-validator issues on Mac OS Ventura

Tags: solana-test-validator

I am getting the same issue [outlined here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4258/getting-error-when-running-solana-test-validator) with solana-test-validator on Mac OS Ventura. I'm on the correct runtime, I corrected the maxfiles limit error I got at first, now it seems to crash immediately at extracting genesis.tar.bz2

Comment: Have you tried installing bzip2? Try `brew install bzip2` As suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70314459/solana-start-solana-test-validator-on-linux-ubuntu-blockstore-error