# 'blockstore error' when starting solana-test-validator on MacOS 13.0.1

Tags: error, solana-test-validator, testvalidator

I am trying to start `solana-test-validator`, but it closes unexpectedly with `blockstore error`.

```
Error: failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: blockstore error
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you start validator as `./validator/solana-test-validator`?

Comment: Yes, but i also tried different locations.

Comment: Do you have Rosetta installed btw? I cannot reproduce your issue on my mac (v12 and Rosetta is intalled)

Comment: Yep, rosetta is installed :(

Comment: I guess the problem is with macos v13 since for v12 it works. But I don't know how to check it out without installing

Comment: Could you add to the post output of `rustup show`?

Comment: @KirillLykov done, check please

Comment: all looks to be correct, I've run out of ideas. Probably MacOS version

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are multiple versions of the 'tape archiver' (`tar`) program.

MacOS comes with BSD tar by default:

```
% tar --help | grep bsdtar
tar(bsdtar): manipulate archive files
```

Which is a less popular version of tar than the GNU tar. `solana-test-validator` expects GNU tar.

There is an [issue to resolve the GNU tar dependendency](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/34625). In the meantime, you can work around this issue by replacing BSD tar with a GNU version.

If you haven't [installed homebrew](https://brew.sh/), do that first. Then run:

```
brew install gnu-tar
# Put this in ~/.zshrc 
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

You will now have BSD tar installed.

And then re-run `solana-test-validator`

Comment: this fixed it for me!!

Comment: I have gnu-tar in a different location. After adding  export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/gnu-tar/1.34_1/libexec/gnubin:$PATH" to ~/.zshrc it was fixed.

Comment: This also fixed it for me on MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 M1 with solana-cli 1.14.18 and rustc pinned to 1.65.0 using a rust-toolchain.toml

Comment: this fixed my problem though the error log is different: 'Error: failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: io error: Error checking to unpack genesis archive: Archive error: extra entry found: "._genesis.bin" Regular'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

```
solana-test-validator --reset
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If you're facing the same error even after installing `gnu-tar`. Try removing the test-ledger folder `rm -rf test-ledger` and try again.