# validator boostrapping fails when trying to unzip genesis.tar.bz2 on MacOS

Tags: validator, bootstrap

The **genesis.tar.bz2** archive gets rejected because it contains unwanted entries (see below):

Error:

> extra entry found: "._genesis.bin" Regular"

Content seen by the affected method:

```
file: Ok("._genesis.bin")
file: Ok("genesis.bin")
file: Ok("._rocksdb")
file: Ok("rocksdb/")
file: Ok("rocksdb/._000004.log")
file: Ok("rocksdb/000004.log")
file: Ok("rocksdb/._IDENTITY")
file: Ok("rocksdb/IDENTITY")
file: Ok("rocksdb/._LOCK")
file: Ok("rocksdb/LOCK")
file: Ok("rocksdb/._OPTIONS-000079")
file: Ok("rocksdb/OPTIONS-000079")
file: Ok("rocksdb/._CURRENT")
file: Ok("rocksdb/CURRENT")
file: Ok("rocksdb/._LOG")
file: Ok("rocksdb/LOG")
file: Ok("rocksdb/._MANIFEST-000005")
file: Ok("rocksdb/MANIFEST-000005")
file: Ok("rocksdb/._OPTIONS-000081")
file: Ok("rocksdb/OPTIONS-000081")
```

here is the more verbose output:

```
    panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Io(Custom { kind: Other, error: "Error checking to unpack genesis archive: Archive error: extra entry found: \"._genesis.bin\" Regular" })'
```

Reproduction on solana  v1.15.2 (using Mac):

- cargo test --test program

Comment: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4499/cant-start-solana-test-validator-on-macos-13-0-1/4761#4761

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are running spotlight on your git checkout:

Add the folder to the list of search except paths using System Preferences > Spotlight > privacy tab.