# Getting error on solana-test-validator

Tags: solana-cli, solana-test-validator

```
failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: io error: Error checking to unpack genesis archive: Archive error: extra entry found: "._genesis.bin" Regular/failed to stash problematic rocksdb: Directory not empty (os error 66)
```

Getting error while runn solana-test-validator on mac

I have tried doing this
['blockstore error' when starting solana-test-validator on MacOS 13.0.1](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4499/blockstore-error-when-starting-solana-test-validator-on-macos-13-0-1/4761#4761)

but it's still not working

Comment: Are you trying to run "solana-test-validator" from within the program directory in your terminal? I made the same mistake and have received the same error before.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on an M1 mac running Sonoma 14.2.1, but my Intel mac running Sonoma 14.2.1 runs solana-test-validator just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might just need to delete the ledger directory and try again, ie:

```
rm -rf test-ledger
solana-test-validator
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue too.  (Apologies if this is the wrong place to put this, I don't know how to delete this answer).

➜  dev solana-test-validator

Notice! No wallet available. `solana airdrop` localnet SOL after creating one

Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
Error: failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: io error: Error checking to unpack genesis archive: Archive error: extra entry found: "._genesis.bin" Regular