Can't run local validator on MAC
Hello I'm getting the following error:
Error: failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: io error: Error checking to unpack genesis archive: Archive error: extra entry found: "._genesis.bin" Regular
When trying to run solana-test-validator. I am deleting the test-ledger folder after and when I retry it happens again

The answer to this other question worked for me: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4499/blockstore-error-when-starting-solana-test-validator-on-macos-13-0-1

The problem is that I am using an M1 device. https://gist.github.com/lorisleiva/41ef16a92af68a205a8eea6703d8e6d5
this post details a solution on how to install solana cli locally for M1.

That post is quite old, and the Solana releases now contain M1 builds. Your issue is not related to that. You would get an error about an unsupported instruction set if it were the issue.
